# Is there any option to get a copy of D2C message sent by IOT hub using c#

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I'm working on an IOT project, my hardware device is not able to read message header. So not able to send feedback to IOT hub, because i don't have the ETag. Is there any way to get a copy of the message that sent to the device from IOT hub., so that i can save the etag and and can provide to the device when it requests.

Or is there any other way to solve my issue.

Comment: The Azure IoT hub has nothing to do with how *your device and code* works. What device, what language, what SDK and why can't you read message headers? An HTTP response is a simple *string*. Some parts of that string are the headers, some others are the body. If you can read an HTTP response, you can read the headers.

Comment: I'm asking this behalf of a hardware developer and i'm using azure IOT SDK and c# is my language.

Comment: You should update the question title from "D2C" to "C2D".  Also it's not clear why the device needs the message ETag, you could expand the question providing more information about the use of ETag. Generally speaking, the device should just accept or reject the message.

Comment: @SyamKumar, The Etag header is returned in all requests scoped to a single device identity.